# Shell namespace extension registry on windows 10 IOT enterprise

Tags: windows, shell, shell-extensions, windows-10-iot-enterprise, shell-namespace-extension

I am creating a virtual folder with shell namespace extension on windows 10 IOT enterprise.
The code I am using come from windows 7 SDK samplesm which is provided by microsoft.
Here is the whole project: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/winui/shell/shellextensibility/explorerdataprovider

This project runs perfectly on windows 7 and windows 10, but after run "regsvr32 explorerdataprovider.dll" on windows 10 iot enterprise, the virtual folder icon does show up under "my computer", but after I double click the icon, nothing happens.
[image]

so I debug into that and found out the function `DllGetClassObject` is never being called.
My guess is that the windows 10 iot enterprise registry for shell namespace extension is different with windows 10, so I searched online to try to add enough registry key, so far the registry I am using is:

```
 REGSTRUCT rgRegEntries[] =
{
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s",                  szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32",  szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)L"%s",              REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32",  szFolderViewImplClassID, L"ThreadingModel",      (LPBYTE)L"Apartment",       REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\DefaultIcon",     szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)L"shell32.dll,-42", REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\ShellFolder",     szFolderViewImplClassID, L"Attributes",          (LPBYTE)&dwData,            REG_DWORD,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s",                  szContextMenuClassID,    NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32",  szContextMenuClassID,    NULL,                   (LPBYTE)L"%s",              REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32",  szContextMenuClassID,    L"ThreadingModel",      (LPBYTE)L"Apartment",       REG_SZ,

    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"CLSID\\%s", szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL, (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle, REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32", szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL, (LPBYTE)L"%s", REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32", szFolderViewImplClassID, L"ThreadingModel", (LPBYTE)L"Apartment", REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"CLSID\\%s\\DefaultIcon", szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL, (LPBYTE)L"%s,0", REG_SZ,
    HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"CLSID\\%s\\ShellFolder", szFolderViewImplClassID, L"Attributes", (LPBYTE)&dwData, REG_DWORD,

    ////----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\MyComputer\\NameSpace\\%s",szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\MyComputer\\NameSpace\\DelegateFolders\\%s",szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,

    HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\MyComputer\\NameSpace\\%s",szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,

    //HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"\\%s",szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Shell Extensions\\Approved",szFolderViewImplClassID, NULL,                   (LPBYTE)g_szExtTitle,       REG_SZ,

    ////----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // For performance, only context menu verbs that register this are considered when the user double-clicks.
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\%s\\ShellEx\\MayChangeDefaultMenu",                szContextMenuClassID, NULL,  (LPBYTE)L"",                  REG_SZ,
    // register the context menu handler under the FolderViewSampleType type.
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,   L"Software\\Classes\\FolderViewSampleType\\shellex\\ContextMenuHandlers\\%s",  szContextMenuClassID, NULL,  (LPBYTE)szContextMenuClassID, REG_SZ,
};
```

But it still doesn't work.

Is there any registry key for shell namespace extension for virtul folder is missing ?

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Enterprise shouldn't be different from a technical perspective, it's the same product as Windows 10 (Enterprise): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86c34321-c8bd-46d4-937f-7fda2e249410/is-windows-10-enterprise-and-windows-10-iot-enterprise-the-same?forum=WindowsIoT unless the image is tweaked to remove some features, but it's up to the final distributor AFAIK, it's not general to "Windows 10 IoT Enterprise"

Comment: @beasone,
Did you find any solution?
I have same problem in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but there are 2 locations in the registry for virtual folders (they have very similar paths, so it's easy to miss):

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace
```

Also, on Win10 x64, don't forget to add your virtual folder to the **WOW6432Node** equivalent:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace
```